# how delete Auto redirect Url in Yoast seo premium

Tags: wordpress, seo, yoast

In Yoast seo premium when change post url, old url automatically redirect to new url, where this url saved ? and how i can remove or delete this redirect?

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific section of the plugin called **Redirect**, where you can manage (insert, edit, delete) all the redirects on your website.

Comment: Manually Redirect appear in Redirects section not automatically redirections, and my problem is automatically redirects

Comment: Both manual and automatic redirects appears in that section. Just search for the slug you want to edit.

Comment: Thanks. yes i search and find slug. thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

You can disable Yoast SEO automatic redirects for post/page/terms changes like adding this codes into your theme's functions.php file :

```
add_filter('Yoast\WP\SEO\post_redirect_slug_change', '__return_true' );

add_filter('Yoast\WP\SEO\term_redirect_slug_change', '__return_true' );
```

More information here :
https://developer.yoast.com/customization/yoast-seo-premium/disabling-automatic-redirects-notifications/